# Land in 2E Air France CDG. Want to use the AF lounge in 2E

Tags: airports

I Arrive AF Terminal 2E Paris from SFO and connecting to a flight to Spain on AF terminal 2F. Can I use the lounge in 2E after I land or do I have to pass customs and go to 2F? I am flying business class

Comment: 2E has 3 piers (K, L, M gates), each with its own lounge. Any specific reason you want to use one of those rather than the lounge in 2F? They're all just as bland and uninteresting as each other.